# count(distinct) over (partition by... doesn't work in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, window-functions

[image]

I want to count the `distinct` `day_number` over the past 30 days. However, the distinct function can't be used with `over`

If I delete `distinct`, it will give me the total count of the `day_number`, but `day_number` can have lots of duplicate. So that's why I want to add `distinct`.

```
select tr.*,
       count( distinct day_number) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT ORDER BY DAY_number range 29 PRECEDING) as result
from table tr;
```

Can anyone please show me how to count the distinct numbers in the `over(partition by..)` statement? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it would be easier if you supplied data, but look into the COLLECT (an aggregate function that assembles a collection of values), SET (which turns a collection into a set by removing duplicates) and CARDINALITY (which returns the count of rows in a collection). You may need to explicitly handle nulls.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To be more specific, day_number is the list of days in numeric forms, for example, 1970.1.1 is considered as 1 and so on. The table contains all the transactions for each accounts at the date(day_number). One account can have many associated day_numbers. My goal is to count the distinct day_number for the past 30 days for each account. The above code I provided works well if I want the total count. But I want the distinct count.

Comment: What does "1970.1.1 is considered as 1 and so on" mean? Is it the first of January 1970 (so DAY_NUMBER's datatype is DATE), or ...? Does it have to be an analytic count? How about an aggregate COUNT function with a WHERE clause (to restrict "day numbers" to last 30 days)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by first creating a column that only lists each id once, and then doing a range-count on that column, e.g.:

```
WITH sd AS (SELECT 1 ID, 10 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 ID, 20 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID, 30 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID, 40 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 ID, 50 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 ID, 60 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 6 ID, 70 val FROM dual)
SELECT ID,
       val,
       COUNT(id_distinct) OVER (ORDER BY ID RANGE 3 PRECEDING) cnt_disinct_ids
FROM   (SELECT ID,
               val,
               CASE WHEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY val) = 1 THEN ID END id_distinct
        FROM   sd);

        ID        VAL CNT_DISINCT_IDS
---------- ---------- ---------------
         1         10               1
         1         20               1
         2         30               2
         2         40               2
         4         50               3
         4         60               3
         6         70               2
```

---

ETA: proof that the above technique works for your data:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 'ABCDE' account_sk, 23 day_sk FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'ABCDE' account_sk, 23 day_sk FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'ABCDE' account_sk, 24 day_sk FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'ABCDE' account_sk, 25 day_sk FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'ABCDE' account_sk, 53 day_sk FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'ABCDE' account_sk, 53 day_sk FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'ABCDE' account_sk, 55 day_sk FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'VWXYZ' account_sk, 10 day_sk FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'VWXYZ' account_sk, 12 day_sk FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'VWXYZ' account_sk, 40 day_sk FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'VWXYZ' account_sk, 40 day_sk FROM dual)
SELECT account_sk,
       day_sk,
       COUNT(day_sk_distinct) OVER (PARTITION BY account_sk ORDER BY day_sk RANGE BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) count_distinct_day_sk
FROM   (SELECT account_sk,
               day_sk,
               CASE WHEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY account_sk, day_sk ORDER BY day_sk) = 1 THEN day_sk END day_sk_distinct
        FROM   your_table);

ACCOUNT_SK     DAY_SK COUNT_DISTINCT_DAY_SK
---------- ---------- ---------------------
ABCDE              23                     1
ABCDE              23                     1
ABCDE              24                     2
ABCDE              25                     3
ABCDE              53                     3
ABCDE              53                     3
ABCDE              55                     2
VWXYZ              10                     1
VWXYZ              12                     2
VWXYZ              40                     2
VWXYZ              40                     2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried the above code, but it still doesn't work.          select 
  count(tr.day_sk) over (order by tr.ACCOUNT_SK range 29 preceding) cnt_distinct_ids
  from (select tr.*
  , case when row_number() over (PARTITION BY tr.ACCOUNT_SK ORDER BY tr.DAY_SK)=1 then tr.ACCOUNT_SK end id_distinct
  from aggTxn2 tr)

Comment: What do you mean by “doesn’t work”? Do you get an error? Wrong results? Something else?

Comment: I got error message like this '''''ERROR: ORACLE prepare error: ORA-00904: "TR"."ACCOUNT_SK": invalid identifier. SQL statement: select 
       count(tr.day_sk) over (order by tr.ACCOUNT_SK range 29 preceding) cnt_distinct_ids from (select tr.* , case when 
       row_number() over (PARTITION BY tr.ACCOUNT_SK ORDER BY tr.DAY_SK)=1 then tr.ACCOUNT_SK end id_distinct from aggTxn2 tr) ''''''' However, I don't think it's the problem of "TR".

Comment: It is; your outer query doesn’t have an alias of “tr”, only your inline view does. Remove the `tr.`s from your outer query and it’ll work.

Comment: Thank you! The "TR" problem is fixed and the code can run now. I got the count of the total volume for the day_sk over past 30 days. But I want the count of distinct volume for the day_sk over the past 30 days. Only problem is the 'distinct'. Here is my code, do you have any suggestion to fix it? Thanks a lot! select 
  count(day_sk) over (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_SK ORDER BY DAY_SK range 29 PRECEDING) cnt_distinct_ids
  from (select tr.*
  , case when row_number() over (PARTITION BY tr.ACCOUNT_SK ORDER BY tr.DAY_SK)=1 then tr.ACCOUNT_SK end id_distinct
  from aggTxn2 tr)

Comment: In what way does that not give you the results you’re after? Please update your question to include sample data, the output you get with the latest query, and the output you’re expecting (as text).

Comment: I've added a picture link in the question, please take a look. Thank you!

Comment: So, the technique in my answer would give you the desired results. Also, please turn your picture into text; not everyone can see the images.

Comment: I have updated my answer to demonstrate that the technique does indeed work for your data.

Answer (score 3):

The `count(distinct ...)` works fine with the over clause, the main problem it's the order by. You can't do `count (distinct ..) over (partition by ... order by ...)` because DISTINCT functions and RATIO_TO_REPORT cannot have an ORDER BY. So i did this:

```
select tr.*, count (distinct day_number) over (partition by account)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by account order by day_number) row_number from table t) tr
where row_number < 30;
```

I've tested it in employees scheme of HR (Free oracle scheme that you can find everywhere)
I'm not sure it will works in your schema because i have not a replica of it, but, if not, it should give you some ideas:

```
 select count (distinct manager_id) over (partition by department_id), department_id, manager_id
from (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by department_id order by employee_id) row_number from employees e)
where row_number < 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate this by creating an column that will be 1 when a "new break" appears in the ordered list and null otherwise. Then you just have to count or sum these break indicators. And both count() and sum() support "over(order by...)".
On your example, it will be:

```
with TR as
(select 1 as PK, 'ABCDE' as ACCOUNT, 23 as DAY_number from dual
union all select 2, 'ABCDE', 23 from dual
union all select 3, 'ABCDE', 24 from dual
union all select 4, 'ABCDE', 25 from dual
)
select tr.*
    ,  count( /*distinct*/ day_number) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT ORDER BY DAY_number range 29 PRECEDING) as wrong_result
    ,  count(IS_NEW_BREAK) over(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT order by day_number range 29 PRECEDING) as desired_output
    from
    (select tr.*
        ,   case min(case when day_number is not null then PK end) over(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT, day_number) when PK then 1 end as IS_NEW_BREAK
        from tr
    ) tr;
```