# count(distinct) over (partition by ... range function)

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I want to count the distinct `yyyydd` over the `mm`(date). (+- 2days)
However, the distinct function can't be used with over.

If I delete distinct, it will give me the total count of the `yyyydd`, but `yyyydd` can have lots of duplicate. So that's why I want to add distinct.
It's a bit similar with [count(distinct) over (partition by... doesn't work in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55347200/countdistinct-over-partition-by-doesnt-work-in-oracle-sql) but different :(

```
with tbl1 as 
(select 'tay' cst_name, 'toy1' product_name, '20230501' yyyymmdd from dual union all
select 'tay' cst_name, 'toy1' product_name, '20230502' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
select 'tay' cst_name, 'toy1' product_name, '20230507' yyyymmdd from dual union all
select 'ray' cst_name, 'toy2' product_name, '20230321' yyyymmdd from dual union all
select 'ray' cst_name, 'toy2' product_name, '20230421' yyyymmdd from dual union all
select 'ray' cst_name, 'toy2' product_name, '20230422' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
select 'ray' cst_name, 'toy1' product_name, '20230423' yyyymmdd from dual union all
select 'ray' cst_name, 'toy1' product_name, '20230423' yyyymmdd from dual union all
select 'ray' cst_name, 'toy1' product_name, '20230527' yyyymmdd from dual union all
select 'ray' cst_name, 'toy2' product_name, '20230527' yyyymmdd from dual )
,
tbl2 as(
select a.*, substr(yyyymmdd,1,6) as yyyymm, substr(yyyymmdd ,7,9) as mm
from tbl1 a)

select
b.*
, count(1) over (partition by cst_name, product_name order by to_number(mm) range between 2 preceding and 2 following) as cnt
, count(distinct yyyymm) over (partition by cst_name, product_name order by to_number(mm) range between 2 preceding and 2 following) as cnt -- error
from tbl2 b
```

| cst_name | prod_name | yyyyddmm | mm | cnt(wrong) | cnt(wanted) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tay | toy1 | 20230501 | 01 | 2 | 1 |
| tay | toy1 | 20230502 | 02 | 2 | 1 |
| tay | toy1 | 20230507 | 07 | 1 | 1 |
| ray | toy2 | 20230321 | 21 | 3 | 2 |
| ray | toy2 | 20230421 | 21 | 3 | 2 |
| ray | toy2 | 20230422 | 22 | 3 | 2 |
| ray | toy1 | 20230423 | 23 | 2 | 1 |
| ray | toy1 | 20230423 | 23 | 2 | 1 |
| ray | toy1 | 20230527 | 27 | 1 | 1 |
| ray | toy2 | 20230527 | 27 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`model`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/sql-modeling-data-warehouses.html) clause to emulate window function with operations that are not allowed within them.

```
with tbl1 as (
  select '20230321' yyyymmdd from dual union all
  select '20230327' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230422' yyyymmdd from dual union all
  select '20230423' yyyymmdd from dual union all
  select '20230501' yyyymmdd from dual union all
  select '20230502' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230507' yyyymmdd from dual union all
  select '20230521' yyyymmdd from dual union all
  select '20230523' yyyymmdd from dual union all
  select '20230527' yyyymmdd from dual
)

select *
from tbl1 b
model
  /*To turn off uniqueness check of dimension values*/
  unique single reference
  /*What should be used for offsets*/
  dimension by (substr(yyyymmdd ,7,9) as mm)
  measures (
    /*To include in the output*/
    yyyymmdd,
    /*To allow reference in the right side of RULES*/
    substr(yyyymmdd,1,6) as yyyymm,
    /*Counter for DISTINCT*/
    0 as cnt
  )
  rules update (
      cnt[any] = count(distinct yyyymm)[mm between cv(mm) - 2 and cv(mm) + 2]
  )
order by 1, yyyymmdd
```

| MM | YYYYMMDD | YYYYMM | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 20230501 | 202305 | 1 |
| 02 | 20230502 | 202305 | 1 |
| 07 | 20230507 | 202305 | 1 |
| 21 | 20230321 | 202303 | 3 |
| 21 | 20230521 | 202305 | 3 |
| 22 | 20230422 | 202304 | 3 |
| 23 | 20230423 | 202304 | 3 |
| 23 | 20230523 | 202305 | 3 |
| 27 | 20230327 | 202303 | 2 |
| 27 | 20230527 | 202305 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/N8cAFUyl)

Answer (score 1):

If `distinct` with `order by` in analytic function is not allowed then use subquery:

```
with tbl1 as (
  select '20230321' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230327' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230422' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230423' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230501' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230502' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230507' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230521' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230523' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230527' yyyymmdd  from dual ),


tbl2 as(
  select a.*, substr(yyyymmdd,1,6) as yyyymm, substr(yyyymmdd ,7,2) as dd 
  from tbl1 a)
select yyyymm, dd, 
       (select count(distinct yyyymm) 
       from tbl2 x where dd between b.dd - 2 and b.dd + 2 ) cnt
from tbl2 b order by dd
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/lDWZhC4D)

Comment: Wow Thanks a lot! It works! Btw, actually I have to do group by some columns.

For example, if I add 2 columns cst_name and product_name and group by those columns. So I edit your subquery code 
"select count(distinct yyyymm) 
       from tbl2 x where dd between b.dd - 2 and b.dd + 2 group by cst_name, product_name)"
but ORA-01427 error appear.

Can you help me about this problem?

Comment: Inner query should be correlated with main query through cst_name and product_name, you need to put this condition in `where` clause, something like [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6Kq_izsF). This is my guess, not sure, when I do not see input and desired output.