# count(distinct) over (partition by ... range function) cannot do distinct w/ range

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I want to count the distinct yyyydd over the mm(date). (+- 2days) However, the distinct function can't be used with over.

If I delete distinct, it will give me the total count of the yyyydd, but yyyydd can have lots of duplicate. So that's why I want to add distinct. It's a bit similar with count(distinct) over (partition by... doesn't work in Oracle SQL but different :(

```
with tbl1 as 
(select 'tay' cst_name, 'toy1' product_name, '20230501' yyyymmdd from dual union all
select 'tay' cst_name, 'toy1' product_name, '20230502' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
select 'tay' cst_name, 'toy1' product_name, '20230507' yyyymmdd from dual union all
select 'ray' cst_name, 'toy2' product_name, '20230321' yyyymmdd from dual union all
select 'ray' cst_name, 'toy2' product_name, '20230421' yyyymmdd from dual union all
select 'ray' cst_name, 'toy2' product_name, '20230422' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
select 'ray' cst_name, 'toy1' product_name, '20230423' yyyymmdd from dual union all
select 'ray' cst_name, 'toy1' product_name, '20230423' yyyymmdd from dual union all
select 'ray' cst_name, 'toy1' product_name, '20230527' yyyymmdd from dual union all
select 'ray' cst_name, 'toy2' product_name, '20230527' yyyymmdd from dual )
,
tbl2 as(
select a.*, substr(yyyymmdd,1,6) as yyyymm, substr(yyyymmdd ,7,9) as mm
from tbl1 a)

select
b.*
, count(1) over (partition by cst_name, product_name order by to_number(mm) range between 2 preceding and 2 following) as cnt
, count(distinct yyyymm) over (partition by cst_name, product_name order by to_number(mm) range between 2 preceding and 2 following) as cnt -- error
from tbl2 b
```

| cst_name | prod_name | yyyyddmm | mm | cnt(wrong) | cnt(wanted) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tay | toy1 | 20230501 | 01 | 2 | 1 |
| tay | toy1 | 20230502 | 02 | 2 | 1 |
| tay | toy1 | 20230507 | 07 | 1 | 1 |
| ray | toy2 | 20230321 | 21 | 3 | 2 |
| ray | toy2 | 20230421 | 21 | 3 | 2 |
| ray | toy2 | 20230422 | 22 | 3 | 2 |
| ray | toy1 | 20230423 | 23 | 2 | 1 |
| ray | toy1 | 20230423 | 23 | 2 | 1 |
| ray | toy1 | 20230527 | 27 | 1 | 1 |
| ray | toy2 | 20230527 | 27 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Why do you ask the same question twice?

Comment: I edited the question and I cannot get the answer about the editted post so I asked it again. I'm wondering about how to use groupby function. You can see it through https://stackoverflow.com/a/76380740/21998892

Comment: What group by? It is the same question with the same solution

Comment: I add cst_name and product_name and group by those columns.

Origina table was 
with tbl1 as (
  select '20230321' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230327' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230422' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230423' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230501' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230502' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230507' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230521' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230523' yyyymmdd  from dual union all
  select '20230527' yyyymmdd  from dual )

Comment: Again, it is the same question and the same solution would work: https://dbfiddle.uk/Vl0CM5EL. It would be better to describe what is your issue adapting it to a new structure.

Comment: I "rolled back" the previous question so at least they don'y look almost identical. If you wish to extand a question - I suggest you do that, ADD to the question raher than overwriting it (unless making corrections of course). Note also that the answers provided were for the former detail as well, so they are easier to comprehend against the question.

Comment: see https://dbfiddle.uk/18b1s3-d  this question is considered a duplicate as it is merely a small variant of the former question.